# How to inflate a layout dynamically?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have the following layout defined in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/streamRelativeLayout">
        <ListView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/streamListView"></ListView>
        <ProgressBar android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/streamProgressBar" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

How can I use the LayoutInflater to grab the ListView and the ProgressBar and assign it in code?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In this way:

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_ID, null);
ListView listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.streamListView);
ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.streamProgressBar);
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need the activity reference and call :

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

Then you can grab the two view using their ids

```
relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.anId);
```

Comment: I am having the dynamically created linaerlayout that is LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(context); this layout having some subviews like framelayout, webview. Now, how can I inflate this linearlayout.?

Comment: Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element) because
When inflating a layout, avoid passing in null as the parent view, since otherwise any layout parameters on the root of the inflated layout will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
View convertView;
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.xml.yourxmlname, null);
```

now you can access the items by

```
convertView.findViewById
```

or if you hav lots of Instances, you may define a viewholder

```
static class CalViewHolder {
    ListView con_list;
    Progressbar con_progress;
}
holder = new CalViewHolder();
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.you_xml_id, null);

        ListView list = (ListView)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.streamListView);
        ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.streamProgressBar);
```