# how can I get the properties of an existing view and use it for a dynamic view?

Tags: android, attributes, dynamic-view

I have a .xml file(picture below). In my .xml, the second row's views create while running.

I want my new created views get the same properties from the existing views, like textsize, maxlenght, text-alighn , etc

I tried to change the things that I set for first row views in xml, but some of my codes don't work. for example, this line:

```
            b2.setTextSize(b.getTextSize());
```

doesn't change the TextSize of the second Button.

what can I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDClM.png)

Edit:
Is there a function that could be able to get the whole attributes together and set them for new views?

Comment: Just inflate that same layout for each new row.

Comment: How can I inflate a layout for a specific button or TextView?

Comment: Create a separate layout file with whichever `View`s you want to add at runtime, inflate it like is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070527/how-to-inflate-a-layout-dynamically), and then add it to your existing layout just like you're already doing for the second row.

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the attributes. but now I didn't set Id for any of them. so how can I access to their values? plus, this is just one row of my activity, do I have to repeat 10 xml files (each one for a special row)?

Comment: "I didn't set Id for none of them. so how can I access to their values?" - You need to set IDs for them, and then you can get references to the `View`s as demonstrated in the accepted answer in the linked post. "do I have to repeat one xml for any special row?" - I'm not quite sure what you're asking here, but you can inflate that layout as many times as you want.

Comment: Sorry, my english is bad I think. I used this line to set Id for a button from view. but my program gets error: 
b2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
ContainerLayout.addView(b2);

Comment: and for repeating...I said that because every row has different EditText and TextViews

Comment: "but my program gets error" - You're probably getting an `IllegalStateException` because `b2` is already a child of `view`. You want to add `view` to `ContainerLayout`, not `b2`. "every row has different EditText and TextViews" - Then you can create different layouts for each type of row you have, or you can create layout files that are just a singular `EditText` or `TextView`, inflate however many of each you need for a row, add them to a horizontal `LinearLayout`, and then add that `LinearLayout` to `ContainerLayout`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed "ContainerLayout.addView(b2);" to "ContainerLayout.addView(view);"
Thanks again