# Not able to specify id of the layout file

Tags: android

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBEo6.jpg)I am trying to dynamically add widgets to my app for which I need the layout id, It is not present in the XML file, so I declared one and now when I am trying to access it using the "R.id.layoutid" it is showing as "not resolved" [screenshots[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzdul.jpg)[xml file]

Comment: Doing invalidate cache/restart my fix it if it's a caching problem with Android Studio.

Comment: Post your activity_main file

Comment: posted the XML file

Answer (score 0):

The layout id you are trying to access through `R.id.myid`, is it part of your `activity_main` layout, if not you need to specify the id in xml before accessing.

If you are trying to add a `layout` dynamically then you need to `inflate` the layout.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

[How to inflate a layout dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070527/how-to-inflate-a-layout-dynamically)

Comment: yes I have declared the id as myid in XML file, i just want to add a button