# How to create a framelayout inside a framelayout dynamically in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-framelayout

i am new to android studio,

I am trying to create a FrameLayout of specific size at certain location inside another framelayout dynamically.
here is my following code,

```
        FrameLayout parentLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.tile_container);
        FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        framelayout.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF);
        framelayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        framelayout.SetX(50)
        framelayout.SetY(50)
        parentLayout.addView(framelayout);
```

but i am not getting any layout generated can anyone please help me

Comment: You cannot use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` if the parent of the view is `FrameLayout`. Use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a 32-bit hex value is specified, the two characters corresponding to the colors specify the 8-bit alpha transparency value. This value varies between 00 (completely transparent) and FF (completely opaque).

Hexadecimal colors when used directly through an `int`, must be AARRGGBB. Its hexadecimal color does not specify alpha,
then it is being automatically set to 00.

To set a color to 100% opacity, add FF at the start.

Your code should look like this:

```
FrameLayout parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.tile_container);

FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);
framelayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);
framelayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
framelayout.SetX(50)
framelayout.SetY(50)

parentLayout.addView(framelayout);
```

Alternatively you can use `Color.BLUE`
I hope this helps. ^-^

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `inflate()` function to refer to XML components and create them dynamically

Hope this link helps [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070527/how-to-inflate-a-layout-dynamically)